# .split() at spaces and quotation marks, keep quotation marks - Regex/Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I would like to return an array from a string. The array should contain all characters as separate elements, except for spaces. My current regex looks like this:

```
str = 'Stuff in "quotation marks"';
arr = str.split(/(?=["])|[\s+]/);
console.log(arr);
// [ 'Stuff', 'in', '"quotation', 'marks', '"' ]
```

I would like it to return something like this:

```
// [ 'Stuff', 'in', '"', 'quotation', 'marks', '"' ]
```

What regex can I use to return the " in front of '"quotation' as a separate element in the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`String.prototype.match()`<sup><sub>*MDN*</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
const str = 'Stuff in "quotation marks"';
const arr = str.match(/\w+|"/g);
console.log(arr);
```

PS: Beware that `\w` is analogous for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

---

You can also `.split(/\b/)` at word boundaries `/\b/` but than trim and filter out empty values from the array:

```js
const str = 'Stuff in "quotation marks"';
const arr = str.split(/\b/).map(w=>w.trim()).filter(w=>w);
console.log(arr);
```

**Disclaimer:** the above examples will not work for special characters like š, ç, etc...

Comment: `['"]` - might as well match single quotes too I suppose.

Comment: @RyanWheale well... Not sure what's the exact OP's use case. But say you have *`Let's`*, I'd rather keep it as a single word.